# Implementing repositories with EF Core without creating multiples methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, repository, unit-of-work

I've been using EF core in my project for years without repositories layer and now I decided to implement repositories pattern for one of my projects which became very big. We have more than 30 entity models and a huge list of API endpoints.

The thing is, each endpoint returns to the client the necessary data from DB formatted by the frontend needs. Some times we want just a list of an entity, other times the same list with some related data and sometimes use some SQL aggregate functions to do some calculations.

We just use the DBContext directly in each endpoint to perform the queries as we need, but when implementing the repositories, we faced an effort obstacle which is coding several methods to get the different data formatted to our needs. Not only basic CRUD and some more operations.

My question is, this really how thing are done (creating as much methods as needed) or is there any best practices to this? Is there some way "rewrite" the DBContext so that I can use expressions and turn it generic avoiding creating so mach methods?

Thank you very much!

Comment: STOP! Do not implement your own repositories with EF. You are specifically not supposed to because EF already does it. The DbContext is a unit of work and each DbSet is a repository.

Comment: The real thing it's use generic repo, generic service, and everytime you need some data from a db context most people use GetAsync (with LINQ) and automapper for entities to the DTOs for frontend, i will update an answer using generics if you need it

Comment: Thank you guys. @jmcilhinney, I see a lot of discussion about this. Some agree to not use repositories with EF, but others say it's good for testing and makes life easier when using multiple DB sources or when the framework needs to be changed in the future.

Comment: @LeandroToloza, thank you. I'll take a look at this. I'd appreciate if you could share more details about it.

Comment: Dont use Mappers for objects! EVER! 
Implement an interface (partial class) on your autogenerated classes, that will work with your mapping into a domain objects. 
This is usually faster, doesn't have any framework syntax in it, and is therefor much easier to read and modify. 

Mappers are for people who don't know how interfaces work. (In C# )
And to those people I say: "Figure it out, it's not that hard!".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share my actual BaseRepo

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal ApplicationDbContext Context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public BaseRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual async Task AddAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        await dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
        await SaveAsync();
    }

    public virtual async Task AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        await dbSet.AddRangeAsync(entities);
        await SaveAsync();
    }

    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await dbSet.ToListAsync();
    }

    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
            query = query.Where(filter);

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
            return await orderBy(query).ToListAsync();
        else
            return await query.ToListAsync();
    }

    public virtual async Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(int? id)
    {
        return await dbSet.FindAsync(id);
    }

    public async Task Remove(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Remove(entity);
        await SaveAsync();
    }

    public async Task RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        dbSet.RemoveRange(entities);
        await SaveAsync();
    }

    public virtual async Task<TEntity> SingleOrDefaultAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return await dbSet.SingleOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
    }

    public virtual async Task Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        Context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await SaveAsync();
    }

    public virtual async Task UpdateRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entitiesToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.AttachRange(entitiesToUpdate);
        Context.Entry(entitiesToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await SaveAsync();
    }

    public async Task SaveAsync()
    {
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public virtual async Task AddUpdateOrDeleteRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entitiesToAddOrUpdate)
    {
        await Context.BulkInsertOrUpdateOrDeleteAsync<TEntity>(entitiesToAddOrUpdate.ToList(), new BulkConfig { SetOutputIdentity = false });
        await SaveAsync();
    }
    public virtual async Task AddOrUpdateRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entitiesToAddOrUpdate)
    {
        await Context.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync<TEntity>(entitiesToAddOrUpdate.ToList(), new BulkConfig { SetOutputIdentity = false });
        await SaveAsync();
    }
}
```

The bulk ones are extensions from EFCore.BulkExtensions;

Unit of Work

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable, IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private ExampleRepository _exampleRepository;

    IDisposable _disposableResource = new MemoryStream();
    IAsyncDisposable _asyncDisposableResource = new MemoryStream();

    public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public IExampleRepository ExampleRepository=> _exampleRepository = _exampleRepository ?? new ExampleRepository(_context);

    public async Task<int> CommitAsync()
    {
        return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        await DisposeAsyncCore();
        Dispose(disposing: false);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _disposableResource?.Dispose();
            (_asyncDisposableResource as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
        }

        _disposableResource = null;
        _asyncDisposableResource = null;
    }

    protected virtual async ValueTask DisposeAsyncCore()
    {
        if (_asyncDisposableResource is not null)
        {
            await _asyncDisposableResource.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        if (_disposableResource is IAsyncDisposable disposable)
        {
            await disposable.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        else
        {
            _disposableResource?.Dispose();
        }

        _asyncDisposableResource = null;
        _disposableResource = null;
    }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Example> Examples { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    {
    }
}
```

Hope it help's you!

Answer (score 1):

Create a base Crud class, something like this:

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, new()
```

Then create a set of standard methods:

```
 public virtual TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            using (var scope = ScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var Context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ubContext>();
                var item = Context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
                return item;
            }
        }

        public List<TEntity> GetList(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            using (var scope = ScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var Context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ubContext>();
                var item = Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).AsNoTracking().ToList();
                return item;
            }
        }

        public IQueryable GetListQueryable<TContext>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            using (var scope = ScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var Context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ubContext>();
                var item = Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
                return item;
            }
        }
```

You can also do an insert, or update:

```
public virtual void Update(TEntity input, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            using (var scope = ScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var Context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ubContext>();
                if (input == null)
                    return;

                var existing = Context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);

                if (existing != null)
                {
                    Context.Entry(existing).CurrentValues.SetValues(input);
                    Context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }

        public virtual void Insert(TEntity input)
        {
            using var scope = ScopeFactory.CreateScope();
            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ubContext>();
            context.Set<TEntity>().Add(input);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Now, if you need to make something specific in terms of an overload, or some "wonky" handling, you create a class that inherits from this base class.
(But with the specific name of table as the TEntity)
And now you can employ polymorphism to change the behaviour or create new behavior however you like.

Also you may not be required to make a scoped approach to processing the requests, this is just "yoinked" out of an existing code base I already made that did have it as a requirement.

If this doesn't make sense, let me know, and I will give you more code, from the project.

Comment: Very good and self explanatory! Thank you very much. Now in case if I need GetListQueryable with some related data included and then other one with different related data... How can I make it more generic so I can use the same GetListQueryable and pass all the specifications available in DBContext like Include, ThenIncluce, OrderBy...?

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class DBAccess
{
   private readonly DbContext _db;

   public DBAccess(DbContext db)
   {
     _db = db;
   }

   protected virtual IQueryable<T> Get<T>() where T : class
   {
     return _db.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
   } 
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
private ApplicationUser GetUser(int id)
{
  return _dbAccess.Get<ApplicationUser>().Where(w => w.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```